# Using Redis in Blazor WASM App Not working as expeted

Tags: redis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, stackexchange.redis

Anyone have experience with Redis caching for Blazor WASM? I created a caching service I inject into my controllers. When I make a request to a controller to get data, I first check the cache to see if it exists (using a key).

If it exists, I return that data, if it does not exist, I pull from the database and before I return that data, I send the data to the Redis cache. This seems to work but I have noticed a few quirks I cannot explain:

1. I do not see this data in Redis Stack website running on localhost:8001.
2. I deployed Redis and the Redis Stack developer tool using Docker.  Even when I shut the image down, my app will still return the cached data. How is this possible if Redis is not running (I did not deploy with volumes)

Is Redis caching in the browser instead of the Redis Cache? If so, I do not see the value of using Redis? If it is caching in the browser, how would I know when the data is invalidated?

Here is what my caching service looks like:

```
public class CacheService : ICachService
{
    private readonly IDatabase _cacheDatabase;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration

    public CacheService (IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        var redisURL = _configuration.GetSection("RedisSettings:Url");
        var redis = ConnectionMultiplex.Connect(redisURL);
        _cacheDatabase = redis.GetDatabase(0);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetData(string Key)
    {
        var value = await _cacheDatabase.StringGetAsync(key);
        // if not null, serialize and return
    }

    public async Task<Bool> SetData<T>(string Key, T value, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
    {
        var expiryTime = expirationDate.DateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        return await _cacheDatabase.StringSetAsync(key, JsonSerialize(value), expiryTime);
        // if not null, serialize and return
    }

    public async Task<object> RemoveData(string key)
    {
        //check if it exists and if so, remove it from Redis
    }
}
```

I can then inject this into my other services and use it like this:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<MyObjects>>> GetMyObjects()
{
    var cacheData = await _cacheService.GetData<IEnumerable<MyObjects>>("someUniqueKey");
    // if not null or empty, return the data
    // if null or empty get the data from the db and then cache it
    var myObjs = await _dbContext.MyObjects.ToListAsync();
    await _cachService.SetData<IEnumerable<MyObjects>>("someUniqueKey", byObjs, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5));

    return new ServiceResponse<List<MyObjects>>{Data = myObjs, Success = true};
}
```

And if it helps, this is the relevant part of my Docker Compose file:

```
Services:
   redis:
     image: redis/redis-stack:latest
     restart: always
     environment:
        REDIS_ARGS:  "--requirepass password --user username on >password ~* allcommands --user default off nopass nocommands"
     ports:
       - "6379:6379"
       - "8001:8001"
```